# Necessary condition for Hermician lin operators

Tags: operator-theory, quantum-mechanics, adjoint-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and define $T: H \to H$ as a linear unbounded operator.

Say that the spectrum of $T$ is real and the eigenvectors are orthogonal and span the space.

Does that imply that $T$ is Hermitian? If not, what other conditions need to be satisfied?

Comment: At the very least, it is necessary for eigenvectors associated with distinct eigenvalues to be mutually orthogonal

Comment: Good point. Is it sufficient?